# An infinitely differentiable function whose derivatives are all zero at a point

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$-function such that $f(x)=0$ iff $x\in\mathbb Z$. Suppose the function $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies  $x'(t)=f(x(t))\ \forall t\in \mathbb R$. Then show the following:
>
> (a) If $\mathbb Z\cap\{x(t):t\in \mathbb R\}$ is non-empty, $x$ is constant.
>
> (b) If $\mathbb Z\cap\{x(t):t\in \mathbb R\}$ is the empty set, $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(t)$ exists and is an integer.

As for (a), since $\mathbb Z\cap\{x(t):t\in\mathbb R\}\neq\emptyset$, there has to be a point at which all the derivatives of $x$ has to be zero. I am not sure how to proceed after this.

For (b), $\mathbb Z\cap\{x(t):t\in\mathbb R\}=\emptyset$ implies $x$ is a monotone and also that $x$ can only take values between two consecutive integers. Not sure how this helps though, in proving that the $\lim$ is an integer.

Comment: (a) If $x(t_0)\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $x'(t_0)=f(x(t_0))=0$. So, $y(t)=x(t_0)$ is a solution of the Cauchy problem $\begin{cases}x'&=f(x)\\ x(t_0)&=x(t_0)\end{cases}$. Apply the uniqueness theorem.

Comment: (b) Monotonic and bounded, then the limit $L=\lim_{x\to\infty}x(t)$ exists. Since the limit exists so does the limit $f(L)$ of $f(x(t))$ and therefore the limit $f(L)$ of $x'(t)$. We can use now the mean value theorem. For each $t$ there is $c_t\in(t,t+1)$ such that $\frac{x(t+1)-x(t)}{(t+1)-t}=x'(c_t)$. Taking limits as $t\to+\infty$ we get $0=\lim_{x\to+\infty}x'(t)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x(t))=f(L)$. Therefore, $L$ is an integer.

Comment: @KLstream I am looking for a more fundamental argument for (a)

Comment: Replace the invocation of the uniqueness theorem, by one of the proofs of the uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Which PDE? There are no PDEs anywhere. ODEs will always be involved, since the problem itself is an ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Since any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an equilibrium point, uniqueness means that any solution cannot pass through any member of $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence if $x(t_0) \in [n,n+1]$ for some $t_0$ then $x(t) \in [n,n+1]$ for all $t$.

Since the only zeros of $f$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ then on each $(n,n+1)$ $f$ must be strictly
positive or strictly negative and hence
$x(t)$ is always monotonic and bounded hence it converges, say $x(t) \to x^*$. Since $f(x(t))$ must also converge, and $x$ is bounded we must have $f(x^*) = 0$ and hence 
$x^*$ must be an integer.

(a) Suppose $x(t_0) = n$ for some integer, then the first paragraph shows that $x(t_0) \in [n,n+1]$ and $x(t_0) \in [n-1,n]$ for all $t$ and hence $x(t) = n$ for all $t$.

(b) Follows from the second paragraph.